# Convert a bitmap to mat and vice versa in OpenCV

Tags: opencv3.0, android, opencv

I have an Android Bitmap in my code and I would like to run the 
cvCanny method on it. However, it needs to be in a Mat first. How do I 
convert the data to Mat, and how do I convert it back to Bitmap when 
I'm done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First import `org.opencv.android.Utils`

Then use:

```
Mat src = new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, src);
```

To perform edge detection:

```
Mat dest = new Mat();
Imgproc.Canny(src, dest, min, max);
Bitmap edgeBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(dest, edgeBitmap);
//edgeBitmap is ready
```